# angular button function run when the page loads

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-scope

I have a `ng-click button` that as soon as the page loads it execute Save();
As soon as it load the page even before I click on Submit button, it add empty data to database,
why it does not wait to be clicked?
what can I do to fix it?

```
<div class="col-md-2">
   <button ng-click="Save()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

This is a part of my controller :

```
var App = angular.module("App", ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
App.controller('autoCompleteCTRL', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'MyServices', function ($scope, $rootScope, MyServices) {

    $scope.Save = function () {
        var VCISel = angular.copy($scope.searchText);
        var RolesSel = angular.copy($scope.SelectedItems);
        MyServices.AddRole(Sel, "adad",RolesSel)
        .success(function (data) {
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
        });
    };
    $scope.Save();
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your controller definition, you are invoking the `Save` function by doing `$scope.Save();`

Answer (score 2):

Remove `$scope.Save();` at end of `autoCompleteCTRL` controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var App = angular.module("App", ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
App.controller('autoCompleteCTRL', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'MyServices', function ($scope, $rootScope, MyServices) {

    $scope.Save = function () {
        var VCISel = angular.copy($scope.searchText);
        var RolesSel = angular.copy($scope.SelectedItems);
        MyServices.AddRole(Sel, "adad",RolesSel)
        .success(function (data) {
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
        });
    };
}]);
```